# key error in jupyter notebook while converting target variable into array

Tags: arrays, python-3.x, pandas

i am working on a machine learning model in which after one hot encoding i want covert it the target value in to array my target variable is final status in that i am getting key error

```
features = pd.get_dummies(features)
labels = np.array(features['Final Status'])enter image description here
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you want to convert target variable into factors you can use LableEncoder,
how ever you can directly convert to_array(pd.get_summies('Final status'))